# How can I extract http or https after tokenization?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contain text like this

```
>  because she s the worst 
    i am referring to  this   http  iimgurcom5srylmijpg  does it have any deeper meaning or does it signify anything  i just do nt get it why she d do that 
    cheating but zoldycks must have a great time at thanksgiving 
     kurosaki ichigo    http  images5fanpopcomimagephotos29000000ichigowallpaperkurosakiichigo290694271024768jpg  and  kurosaki mea   http  staticzerochannetkurosakimeafull1689483jpg 
    there are a shit ton of koutarous  but the presence of  one   https  smediacacheak0pinimgcomoriginals1219ed1219ed717fc2bfce372759bba2fe1cfegif  is enough to make it the most interesting party.
```

I have extracted tokens by first converting multiple space to single space as the spaces were not uniform using command:

```
words = re.sub('\s+', ' ', sentence).strip()
```

Now, I want to get only http or https as can be seen that there is no proper URL in the text.

I tried with `(http|https)\s` but it didn't work out.

Is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: I think you are doing it int JavaScript!?

Comment: what did you want to get, i really don't get you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to find http or https: `http(s)?(\s+)` see working [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/8).

To get also the http or https in group use `(http(s)?(\s+))` as in the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/9).

Comment: Can I get all the tokens + (http|https) words after doing this as it is only giving the match?

Comment: add more regex to add http(s)